# Installed LLVM 3.5 with apt, now I have to suffix everything with -3.5?

Tags: linux, llvm, linux-mint

I installed LLVM via the apt package manager, (apt-get install llvm-3.5)... now I have to suffix every command and include with -3.5. Is this normal and how it is with LLVM nowadays, or did I screw up the setup? For instance, if I ran llvm-config it won't work so I need to append -3.5 to that. The same goes for including llvm header files in my code.

I'm asking because I'm working on an open source project, so if someone installs it and they don't have the issue with the `-3.5` suffix on everything, then it could break.

I'm using Mint 17 (64 bit), if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the directory that is provided by `llvm-config-3.5 --bindir`. I found the executables without suffix in there. I had the same problem with eclipse CDT not finding my LLVM/Clang installation, but only the LLVM path was wrong.